# AWS Instance stand-alone ssh connect string differences: root vs ec2-user

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, command-line-interface, amazon-web-services

I have an instance I created from the web console, using the "Classic" wizard & the default Amazon Linux image.

When I go to Instance Actions, Connect, and select the "Connect with a standalone SSH Client" option, it has the correct string, using ec2-user@.

I saved that as an AMI, and then created a new instance via the ec2 command-line tools:

```
ec2-run-instances <ami> -k <my key> -g <my security group>
```

Now when I get the connect string, it uses root@, which doesn't work - I need to change that to ec2-user to actually connect.

This isn't a big deal, but I'm wondering why there's a difference - is there a missing parameter when I create it via the command line?

Answer (score 1):

ec2-user and root are two different users on the server. By default, root SSH access is not allowed per /etc/ssh/sshd_config. You could change this, of course, but it's considered a good security practice. (Root is a known, privileged account, and therefore a prime target for attackers.)

How old are your ec2 command-line tools? I'd guess that they used to allow root access previously, but no longer do that.

Comment: It's the AWS web console that's producing the root@ or ec2-user@ ssh commands, depending on whether the command line tool or the web console was used to create the instance.  Tools are all up to date.